# Why is Quelaag hostile?

Tags: dark-souls

In the first Dark Souls, when you enter Quelaag's Domain she attacks you without any discussion or trying to know why you have entered there.

Her sister, however, shows no hostility and neither does her servant, even though you killed Quelaag.

So why would Quelaag be hostile at first sight, and doesn't try to know if you came there to help her sister and give her humanity? Does she have any reason to attack the player instantly?

Any item lore or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: iirc, this is never explained. Other Queelag siblings have some reasons for attacking the player, but not the Chaos Witch Quelaag.

Comment: I didn't read all items of the game and don't plan to (I only have one life afterall) and couldn't check all the vids about dark souls lore so I thought the community here would have an idea, I would be quite sad that there are no explanation, it sounds weird for dark souls :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are several valid guesses as of why Quelaag is hostile from the get-go:

- She protects her sister from any intruders, regardless of motive, to provide humanity for her sister.
- Considering how long she's been there, Quelaag probably doesn't bother questioning motives of intruders at this point due to how hostile literally everything else is in Lordran.

Quelaag's sister - the Fair lady - is blind and weak.
Spoiler:

> if you have the Old Witch's Ring, you will be able to understand what she says, and how she mistakes you - the chosen undead (who can feed her humanity to ease the pain and open a shortcut) - for her caring sister.

Lore-wise, the Fair Lady was transformed into the spider thingy by the Flame of Chaos incident. The reason to why she is weakened (and thus protected by her sister) is because she's attempting to cure Blighttown by sucking up all the blight (Eingyi being one of those whom she helped).

She and Quelaag were two of the only three (the third one being the witch Quelaana who managed to escape with no mutations) whose sanity survived the Flame of Chaos incident that mutated everyone else into demons (as their torsos are still human, so are their minds).

And you killed her sister to ring a bell, and now she's all alone with nobody to care for her, you monster.

For further info and clarification, refer to articles on [the Fair Lady](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/quelaag-s-sister), [Quelaag](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/chaos-witch-quelaag), and [Quelaana](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/quelaana-of-izalith) on their wikidot pages.

Comment: Yeah I agree on that point, but it doesn't really explain why she attacks us without any talk, as you said Quelaag still got her mind and is a reasonnable beeing, so she could ask you if you're here to help the Fair Lady or not, and then attack or not (Yes I know it is a game and sometimes you have to take the logic out to bring out a cool boss but hey, she's intelligent after all). The only hypothesis I have is that quelaag wanna kill you to gather your humanity and feed her sister

Comment: That is a valid hypothesis. It's also possible that she just got sick of asking every single thing that waddles into the Domain.

Comment: yeh it seems like a good reason, they're quite old afterall :-)

Comment: They aged well, I tell you that. So, any information you'd want me to fix before you're satisfied with the answer?

Comment: Maybe just put the two thesis in your answer so it can help other people that see this post then i'll validate it for now :)

Comment: Well, I'm satisfied.

Comment: Who says Quelaag can speek ? .... Maybe she cant. And btw the only Boss thats not instant Hostile and is willing to talk is priscilla as far as i remember.

Comment: @GEnGEr The whole ring thing follows the mention of the Fair Lady. I never said Quelaag can speak.

Comment: +1 for "You Monster" - This is one of the more depressing things in a pretty depressing game (and not just because of rage quitting)

Comment: There is a minor error in your post from my understanding:  Quelanna of Izalith and the Daughter of Chaos are the 2 siblings that did not get mutated. The Fair Lady and Chaos Witch Queelag escaped, but were partially mutated.

Comment: @ColinD Is it the part where I say that "They ['Laag, 'Laana, and Lady] were the only three whose **sanity** survived"?

Comment: @user1337 your right, I did misread part of the answer.  However, it does make me ask the following, did Chaos Witch Queelag actually escape with here sanity? Ceaseless discharge (brother) seems to be pretty sane by the same standards as Queelag too? He only attacks after you disrupt the tomb he is guarding. Do we know that the Daughter of Chaos has lost her sanity?

Comment: Ceaseless got fully screwed over unfortunately. He's in constant pain and is guarding the only good memory from his past life (cause he lost his bloody ring). He's fully demon'd, but Fair Lady is perfectly sane, and her sis got the same grade of mutations, so I'd say her course of action is a bit more rational than violence fueled by pain and rage.

Comment: I re-read this post in GlaDOS voice after i see "you monster".

Answer (score 12):

There are actually unused lines of dialogue in the game relating to Quelaag which imply that she may have been planned to be an optional boss at some point during development, much like Priscilla.

The following lines exist as sound files in the game data, and you can listen to them [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VUzHRBc2bQ).

> Go back. Forbidden be, these parts. The realm of the creatures of chaos. They accept their banished fate.
>
> Go back. Lest the flames devour all, and the children of chaos feed upon your charred ashes. Those who defy the pact… Those who trespass Quelaag's domain… May you feel the depth of our wrath!
>
> Ahh, a precious new sacrifice! Forbidden be, these parts. The realm of the creatures of chaos.
>
> Go on, go on ahead…
>
> Welcome, bringer of meat. The children of chaos are hungry; give yourself to Quelaag's flame!

Keep in mind that speaker of these lines can't be confirmed as the lines only exist as sound files, but they seem to show that more of a story was planned for Quelaag and the chaos covenant, which didn't make it into the game for unknown reasons.

It's would make sense if Quelaag being a non-hostile NPC was cut due to development constraints, as much of the areas between Quelaag and the Bed of Chaos, including the Bed of Chaos itself, show signs of being unfinished compared to other parts of the game.

Comment: Interesting bonus to the answer, I didn't know about these sound files... And now that you say it it sure looks like this aera misses something. Could you tell me how you find those gems please? and +1 btw :)

Answer (score 6):

Quelagg is hostile because she is protecting her sister, the Fair Lady. You are an intruder, so she attacks you, regardless of what your intentions actually are, because she can't take the risk that you might find her sister and kill her.

Furthermore, you are obviously not hollow (as in, insane mindless zombie, not hollowed as in offline mode), so if Quelagg kills you, she can (hopefully) get some humanity from you to give to her sister to ease her pain.